# simple logic finding closest upcoming day of the week using Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-2.0

I have an array `days` where the days of the week are numbers.  0 = sunday, 1 = monday, etc.

```
days = [0, 1, 3, 4] # this is just an example, the list is dynamic, it could be any combination of days (non repeating)
```

Given that today is 6 (sat), how can I determine the next closest day **relative** to today's date? (e.g. 0, sunday)

Presently I'm doing this:

```
if days.include?(Date.today.wday)
  quiz_day = Date.today.wday
elsif days.include?(Date.today.wday+1)
  quiz_day = Date.today.wday+1
elsif days.include?(Date.today.wday+2)
  quiz_day = Date.today.wday+2
...
else
  quiz_day = days.first
end
```

Which works, I'm just wondering if there's a simpler solution staring me in the face.

Comment: Can you give the full picture ? I am not understanding... what your want to achieve ?

Comment: Try this `day_number = (0..6).find { |number| number == Date.today.wday }` and then `Date.today.wday + day_number`.

Comment: We have events that go on each week, but some days we have none.  I'm trying to find a way to find the next upcoming day that has events relative to the current day of the week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Selects](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-select) the lowest day `>=` today, otherwise the `first`.

```
def next_quiz_day quiz_days
   quiz_days.select{ |day| day >= Date.today.wday }.min || quiz_days.first
end
```

Assumes a correct (`0..6`) and sorted `quiz_days` array.